# Audio Synthesis with (AVFoundation?) Using Sine Wave

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Let's say I have an array of Y values for a sine wave. (Assume X is time)

In Python you can just write it to a Wav file:

`wav.write("file.wav", <sample rate>, <waveform>)`

Is it possible to do this in Swift using AVFoundation? If so how? If not, what library should I be using? (I'm trying to avoid AudioKit for now.)

Thanks,
Charles

Answer (score 0):

In AVFoundation there is `AVAudioFile`, but you'll have to provide the data as `AVAudioPCMBuffer`s, which keeps the data in a `AudioBufferList`, which in turn consists of `AudioBuffer`s, which are imho all rather complicated since their design goal apparently was to be able to handle every conceivable audio format (including compressed, VBR etc.). So `AVAudioFile` is probably overkill for just writing some synthetic samples to a WAV file.

Alternatively, there is the Audio File Services C-API. It provides `AudioFileCreateWithURL`, `AudioFileWriteBytes` and `AudioFileClose`, which will probably do the trick for your task. 
The most complicated part may be the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` required by `AudioFileCreateWithURL`. To help with this a utility function exists: `FillOutASBDForLPCM`.